# Concatenação em C

Tags: c, c++

Estou fazendo um algoritmo em C para desligar algumas máquinas. Esse é meu algoritmo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

main() {

    char vetor[2][15] = {"192.168.2.200", "192.168.2.201"};

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        system("shutdown -m 192.168.2.200 -s -f");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Porém na linha `system("shutdown -m 192.168.2.200 -s -f \n");` Eu preciso substituir o ip pelo meu `vetor[i]`, mas o comando system só aceita um parâmetro.

### Como posso fazer essa concatenação?

Galera. Testei as opções que me passaram e funcionou. Obrigado.

Porém tenho uma última dúvida.

Se tiver 3 IPs no meu array

E um deles estiver inacessível, tem como fazer uma verificação antes de executar o system? Por exemplo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

    if(vetor[i] == "inacessivel") { //Aqui poderia ser um booleano também, ou int. Coloquei para exemplificar o que desejo fazer
        continue;
}

sprintf(str, "shutdown -m %s -s -f", vetor[i]);
system(str);
}
```

Comment: considere marcar uma das resposta como aceita.

Comment: Você fez ua _segunda_ pergunta que não tem nada em comum com o tema da primeira. Por favor, coloque-a como uma pergunta separada, e marque uma resposta aceita para a pergunta original.

Answer (score 6):

Use a função sprintf,

```
char str[50];
char vetor[2][15] = {"192.168.2.200", "192.168.2.201"};

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    sprintf(str, "shutdown -m %s -s -f", vetor[i]); 
    system(str);
}
```

Para saber mais sobre a função leia [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

**Edit**

Depende como você irá mascarar IPs inacessíveis, supondo que você deixe como um texto vazio poderia ficar assim:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2 /*Tamanho vetor*/; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(vetor[i], "") != 0)
    {
        sprintf(str, "shutdown -m %s -s -f", vetor[i]);
        system(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Só não sei relativo ao tamanho da variável `str`, não contei os caracteres mas me pareceu pouco

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Em `C`, você pode usar a função `sprintf()` da biblioteca padrão `stdio.h` para "montar" o seu comando usando o [especificador de formato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) `%s` em um buffer de `chars`, por exemplo:

```
char buf[256] = {0}
sprintf( buf, "shutdown -m %s -s -f", ips[i] );
system(buf)
```

Adicionalmente, você também pode usar um vetor de ponteiros para char `char*[]` sem especificar as dimensões no lugar de uma array de chars bidimensional `char[2][15]`, isso evita [números mágicos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_m%C3%A1gico_(inform%C3%A1tica)) pelo código, por exemplo:

```
char * ips[] = { "192.168.2.200", "192.168.2.201", "192.168.2.100", "192.168.2.105" };
```

A quantidade de IPs contidos no vetor de ponteiros acima pode ser calculada da seguinte forma:

```
int n = sizeof(ips) / sizeof(ips[0]);
```

Colocando tudo junto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CMD_MAX_TAM     (512)

/* Lista de IPs */
char * ips[] = { "192.168.2.200", "192.168.2.201", "192.168.2.100", "192.168.2.105" };

int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;

    /* Buffer para montagem do comando */
    char cmd[CMD_MAX_TAM+1] = {0};

    /* Calcula quantidade de IPs contidos no vetor */
    int n = sizeof(ips) / sizeof(ips[0]);

    /* Para cada IP do vetor */
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        /* Formata o comando a ser executado */
        sprintf( cmd, "shutdown -m %s -s -f", ips[i] );

        /* Executa comando */
        system( cmd );
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tens o [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) que te permite concatenar duas strings
ou o [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) para formatar a string com as variaveis que pretendes.

exemplo srtcat [como complemento, dica de Jefferson Quesado]

```
char str_destino[80] = "shutdown -m ";
char ip[100] = "192.168.1.15";
strcat (str_destino, ip);
strcat (str_destino," -s -f");

system(str_destino);
//puts (str_destino);
```

O sprintf é mais versátil e permite-te fazer tudo em uma linha de código.

```
sprintf(string_destino, "shutdown -m %s -s -f", string_origem);
```

A variável string_destino guardará a formatação que indicares no sprintf, depois basta usa-la quando for necessário.

```
char string_destino[31];

sprintf(string_destino, "shutdown -m %s -s -f", "127.0.0.1"); 

system(string_destino);
```

Comment: Eu apareceria ver um exemplo com o `strcat`

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Pesquisei um pouco e pensei nisso:

```
string_desliga[31] = "";
char vetor[2][15] = {"192.168.2.200", "192.168.2.201"};    

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        strcat (string_desliga,"shutdown -m ");
        strcat (string_desliga,vetor[i]);
        strcat (string_desliga," -s -f");
        system(string_desliga);
        strcpy(string_desliga,"");
}
```

Referências:
http://www.unicamp.br/fea/ortega/info/aula09.htm
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/ -> tem um exemplo bem simpels pra esse comando que eu usei.

Comment: Acho que você trocou `strcpy` com `strcat`, não? Só o primeiro uso da cópia está certo

Comment: Corrigi lá, obrigado

Comment: Agora o primeiro `strcat` está errado. No segundo laço ele vai colocar algo como `"shutdown -m192.168.2.200 -s -fshutdown -m"` Aproveitando, falta um espaço depois do `-m`, eu creio

Comment: Coloquei o espaço depos do m e o reset na string no final do laço

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

tente,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

main() {
  char vetor[2][15] = {"192.168.2.200", "192.168.2.201"};
  char linhacomando[50];

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  strcpy(linhacomando, "shutdown -m %s -s -f", vetor[i]);
  system(linhacomando);
}

 system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy` copia uma string para outra, não recebe três argumentos. Também não há necessidade da `conio`, uma biblioteca obsoleta, nem necessidade de `system("pause")`

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!